# How to save link data as embedded data with only script without opening spotfire?

Tags: python, spotfire

I am updating new data every day using db connect.
However, due to the large amount of data and unstable db, I want to embed data and distribute it to customers.
The problem is that new data needs to be updated and embedded every day,
but there are many dxp files and cannot be opened in the manual every day.
Can you automate it with Python package or c#?

※ I succeeded in converting the sbdf file.
Just Only Python code (pip install spotfire)
Is there any way to embed with thepython spotfire api?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it with code before but I use Spotfire's automation services to do this all the time.  If you have a spotfire server it should work for you.

Under the tools menu in Spotfire Analyst there is Automation Services job builder. I create a folder in the spotfire library for "published" folders and then setup a job to open the original project and save it in the "published" folder.  The trick is when you save there is a check box to say "embed data in analysis".  You can see in the attached picture, the job only has two steps but you could do a number of open and saves in a row.  I then save the job in the library and schedule it on the server to run nightly.  (Via the spotfire web admin tool, but it can be done on a command line too.)

I then inform users that the published job is updated nightly and opens in a few seconds.  If you need the latest and greatest you can still open the original project and wait the 5-10 minutes it take to load.

[image: Automation Job Screent shot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a right candidate for something like a Automation Services job . You could even create a custom task as  per your use case if needed.

But please be aware of the limitations of the size of the library items in a database. (If the analysis files get too large)

2 GB for SQL Server ,
4 GB for Oracle

See the KB article
https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-48568